# c rand() function and ISAAC random number generator

Tags: c, random

I wrote a program in C that uses a number of different random number generators and one of them is ISAAC (available at http://burtleburtle.net/bob/rand/isaacafa.html). It works well but the problem is that in rand.h rand() is redefined as a macro. In my program I want to use the standard C rand() function as well. I tried changing the name of the macro to rand12() but I cannot see any other place in ISAAC that the macro is called so this doesn't work.

Could you offer some ideas how I can keep the standard rand() function and use ISAAC as well?

Comment: What does the rand macro translate into?

Answer (score 2):

Given that the header `rand.h` contains:

```
#ifndef STANDARD
#include "standard.h"
#endif

#ifndef RAND
#define RAND
#define RANDSIZL   (8)
#define RANDSIZ    (1<<RANDSIZL)

/* context of random number generator */
struct randctx
{
  ub4 randcnt;
  ub4 randrsl[RANDSIZ];
  ub4 randmem[RANDSIZ];
  ub4 randa;
  ub4 randb;
  ub4 randc;
};
typedef  struct randctx  randctx;

/* If (flag==TRUE), then use the contents of randrsl[0..RANDSIZ-1] as the seed. */
void randinit(/*_ randctx *r, word flag _*/);

void isaac(/*_ randctx *r _*/);

/* Call rand(/o_ randctx *r _o/) to retrieve a single 32-bit random value */
#define rand(r) \
   (!(r)->randcnt-- ? \
     (isaac(r), (r)->randcnt=RANDSIZ-1, (r)->randrsl[(r)->randcnt]) : \
     (r)->randrsl[(r)->randcnt])

#endif  /* RAND */
```

You are going to need to do some work to the code to be able to use it alongside `rand()` from `<stdlib.h>`.  The interface to the ISAAC `rand()` is different from the interface to `rand()` from `<stdlib.h>` too.

Create yourself a new header, `"isaac.h"`, which defines cover functions to handle the peculiarities of the ISAAC system.

Maybe, if you aren't going to be working in a threaded context

```
#ifndef ISAAC_H_INCLUDED
#define ISAAC_H_INCLUDED

extern void isaac_init(unsigned long seed);
extern int  isaac_rand(void);

#endif
```

You then implement those functions in `isaac.c` such that they call down onto the functions defined in `rand.h`, and `isaac_rand()` contains an invocation of the `rand()` macro from `rand.h` (providing a context from somewhere, which is where the non-threaded part comes in).  You can decide what to do with the `seed`, or whether to change the seeding mechanism.

You can then use the `isaac_init()` and `isaac_rand()` functions in your code, as well as the normal `rand()` and `srand()`.

I'd also upgrade the code in `rand.h` to provide full prototypes for the functions in the package.  The commented prototypes is a legacy from when it was first written, back in the mid-90s, when standard C compilers were not universally accessible.  The earliest date in the header is 1996; that's just on the cusp of when standard C compilers became almost universally available.

I note that the comments in the header (removed above) say the code is in the public domain; that means it is 100% legitimate to make any modifications you need.

---

#### `isaac.c`

```
#include "isaac.h"
#include "rand.h"

static randctx control;

void isaac_init(unsigned long seed)
{
    assert(seed != 0);
    randinit(&control, FALSE);
}

int isaac_rand(void)
{
    return rand(&control);
}
```

This implementation ignores the seed you give, mainly because the structure expects eight 32-bit numbers to seed the `randrsl` member of the context structure (the one I called `control`).  You could do something like use the seed value 8 times in a row instead of completely ignoring it, or add some number to it each time, or whatever other more complex seeding technique.  You should seriously look at using `/dev/urandom` as a source of the seed:

```
#define DEV_URANDOM "/dev/urandom"

int ur = open(DEV_URANDOM, O_RDONLY);
if (ur >= 0)
{
    read(ur, control.randrsl, sizeof(control.randrsl));
    close(ur);
}
```

You'd put this code into `isaac_init()` before the call to `randinit()`, and you'd change the `FALSE` to `TRUE`.  You'd probably also lose the `seed` argument to the `isaac_init()` function.

This leaves you with a problem of tracking the random seed to gain reproducibility (which can be important when debugging).  That's for you to resolve, though — there are multiple ways to do that.  You might have two initialize functions: `void isaac_init(void)` and `void isaac_rsl(unsigned int *rsl)` which takes an array of 8 `unsigned int` (or `ub4`) values and uses that as the seed instead of the output of `/dev/urandom`.  Or you could pass a null pointer to mean "use output from `/dev/urandom`" and a non-null pointer to mean "use the values I've provided".  Etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt reply. I understand what you are saying but my problem is that the author of ISAAC calls his function rand as well but if I look at rand.h and standard.h there is no call to rand anywhere else (so if I just rename it I cannot find the other parts of the code where I need to make the name changes). There is a rand structure with a number of components, but nothing else. As a result, I have no idea what to edit.

Comment: Strictly, he has a macro called `rand()` which calls a function `isaac()` and otherwise pokes around inside the `randctx` structure.  The one good thing is that a macro has no linkage, so code that does not include the `rand.h` header will never see it, and your wrapper code will conceal the macro from the outside world.  Only the wrapper code uses the ill-named `rand()` macro.  See the updated info in the answer.